# Arm Cortex M3 INVSTATE yet again

Tags: arm

I am working on a system based on a Microchip nee Microsemi nee Actel SmartFusion2 SoC.  This is an FPGA with a hard Cortex M3 core.

I'm running into a hard fault caused by an INVSTATE.  This is usually caused by fogetting to set the LSB in some kind of branch and therefore trying to switch to ARM mode which the Cortex M3 doesn't have.  The weird thing is that it happens when I run my program in the debugger but not if I run the production code.  This would seem to eliminate such an omission in the source code.  Besides, the source in question is the vendor-supplied startup code.  It's not some assembler code I wrote.  Also, its not different between production and debug since it's not being optimized by the toolchain.  It is aseembler source.

The startup code initializes stuff and zeroes the BSS and so on and then, when it calls the main(), function, it hardfaults.  The branch to main() is implemented as ldr pc, =main and the symbol main does have the LSB set.

One of the things I've tried is to examine the EPSR with MRS R2,EPSR and then looking at R2 in the debugger.  It is all zeros on entry into the reset vector and is still zero when the branch to main trriggers the hard fault.  I don't understand why the T bit isn't set since the LSB is set in the reset vector.  And I guess I don't understand why it doesn't fail sooner if EPSR.T is not set.

Any suggestions?  Is the EPSR.T thing a red herring?

Comment: what debugger and how is it controlling stepping, etc (is it doing something that would require the lsbit to be there, and/or not using the lsbit when it is not supposed to be there (the program counter does not hold the lsb bit it is consumed by bx and other instructions)(not sure if any of the program counters even have storage for the lsb bit)...

Comment: can you set a breakpoint and execute normally through a branch or I guess a reset, and see that T bit get set.  I would assume it is either hard coded by logic since this cannot run in arm mode and/or there is a problem (and/or it is a dont care for this architecture/impementation).  I dont think it is a red herring yet.  are you using the debugger to read the epsr?

Comment: I find debuggers useless in general, they cause more problems than they solve, but I would try to continue to insure that in a normal operating mode things are working and the code is correct.  then from single stepping and execute to breakpoint (which some debuggers may do with single stepping btw) it only happens with the debugger.

Comment: and what is your definition of debugger here?   there is the arm logic of course and then there are various debug modules built from other mcus usually that speak swd, and then there is for example openocd that talks to those and then for example gnu gdb that can talk to openocd.  how many layers are you using and for example by pass gdb and talk directly to openocd (telnet) if that is what you are using, etc, etc to isolate if possible what layer is the problem.

Comment: The IDE is an Eclipse port that Microsemi calls "Soft Console."  The debugger is gdb/openocd via a proprietary SWD pod from Microsemi (FlashPro4).  Weird things happen when I try to single-step the jump to main.  Sometimes it hits a breakpoint I have set at the reset exception handler.  Sometimes the debugger/disassembler shows that it has branched to main but as soon as I step the first instruction in main (an ldr from a PC-relative location) it does the same reset thing and hits the earlier breakpoint.

Comment: If I don't set those breakpoints and just tell the debugger to run, it usually hardfaults and I have a breakpoint in the hardfault handler to catch it.   Once in a while it actually starts up and runs.  I've not seen it hardfault or reset once it gets going.

Comment: The debugger shows T to be 0 and I've also put an MRS R2,EPSR in my code and examined R2.  Still zero.  Yes, since it doesn't actually have ARM instructions, you might think T would be ignored or hard wired but then, how come it can get an INVSTATE at all?  I wondered about this and decided maybe they do it for strict adherence to the architecture.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have called the FlashPro4 an SWD pod.  It's JTAG.  Since it came from the silicon vendor, I guess I don't actually know what the protocol running over the JTAG hardware layer is.

Comment: I just tried something that gave me another clue.  After repeated debug launches, it started running normally.  Then I stopped it with the Eclipse pause button (I don't actually know how that translates to gdb).  The T bit is still zero.  So I guess it isn't implemented after all.  This being the case, what could possibly cause an INVSTATE?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Disable the interrupts

Turns out there is another cause for INVSTATE.  This can happen if a load/store instruction executes in the ICI continuation state.  This amounts to re-entering the load/store.  What I didn't realize is that the interrupts are enabled at reset so I didn't see how a continuation state could be entered in the first place.  But the interrupts are enabled at reset.  So I solved the original problem by disabling the interrupts (cpsid if) first thing in the reset handler and not turning them back on (cpsie if) until I have finished initializing all of my peripherals.